# Discord.js disable @evereyone access to new channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need the below code to make channels on command and allow the `member` role to have access to it while the `@everyone` role not have access to it.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'channel',
    description: 'Creates a new channel for the user.',
    aliases: ['channel'],
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message) {
        const userName = message.author.username;
        const channelName = `Channel for ${userName}`;

        message.guild.channels.create(channelName,{
        type: 'text',
        persmissionOverwrites: [
                { 
                    id: message.guild.id,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    deny: ['SEND_MESSAGE'],
                },
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
            ],
        });
        message.channel.send(`Hi ${message.author} your new channel is ${channelName}`);
    },
};
```

I'm aware that this is bare code but I've been struggling to find a way to have the bot find my `member` role and apply the deny to any role even if I were to specify the ID in the ID field.

Comment: Spaces and an arbitrary person's username in a channel name? That's not going to work.

Comment: @Aplet123 The desired name of channel shows up so im happy but the fact that i cant change channel permissions on creation is what im struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason you are not getting any errors or permissionOverwrites is because you wrote `persmissionOverwrites` instead of `permissionOverwrites`

`message.guild.id` does not return a Role or User.

You need to replace `message.guild.id` in the first permission overwrite with [`message.guild.roles.everyone`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=everyone)

You made a typo with one of your permissions `SEND_MESSAGE` which needs to be `SEND_MESSAGES`

Also, you don't need to add `deny` twice, it's an array, you can input as many permissions as you want.

So instead of

```js
deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
```

Write `deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],`

Comment: even with this change the permissions still do not change.

Comment: not even a thing. Just makes the channel and ignores the permission overwrites.

Comment: I added a fix to your code in my answer's edit, could you please give that a try

Comment: still nothing. Im using the code from github and just adding commands on top of it, if that helps in any way.

Comment: I'm not sure what github repo you're referring to.

Comment: https://github.com/discordjs/guide/tree/master/code-samples/command-handling/adding-features/12 This one, once i finished reading the whole guide till this point i had the same code as the github repo, made a new folder for commands and started my own ones.

Comment: Changed it and i got an error
(node:22735) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything, post the full error, on pastebin/hastebin if it's too big

Comment: I edited my answer to fix yet another typo you had that's probably the cause of your error

Comment: 2 major typos, I should go back to school and relearn english. Thank you for your help.